# App Stopped Working After Clicking A Button

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am extremely new to Java programming. Started about a week or two ago. Have some experience with Turing and Visual Basic. Please try and keep explanations as simple as possible. Sorry if the post is kind of messy, first time posting here.

This is my src java file

```
    package com.example.pokethedot;

    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class PokeTheDot extends ActionBarActivity {

        int counter; 
        Button add;
        TextView display;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_poke_the_dot);
            counter=0;
            add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
            display=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
            add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    counter++;
                    display.setText(counter);

                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.poke_the_dot, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

This is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.thenewboston.travis.StartingPoint" 
    android:background="@drawable/background1"
    >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/base_count"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="45sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bAdd"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/thingy"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:minWidth="40dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pokethedot"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ptd"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:logo="@drawable/ptd">
        <activity
            android:name=".PokeTheDot"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my logcat

```
11-12 19:08:04.780: D/dalvikvm(698): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 99K, 3% free 8153K/8327K, paused 34ms, total 36ms
11-12 19:08:04.780: I/dalvikvm-heap(698): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.800MB for 829456-byte allocation
11-12 19:08:04.840: D/dalvikvm(698): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 3% free 8962K/9159K, paused 29ms+3ms, total 61ms
11-12 19:08:05.050: D/gralloc_goldfish(698): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-12 19:09:10.250: W/ResourceType(698): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000001
11-12 19:09:10.250: D/AndroidRuntime(698): Shutting down VM
11-12 19:09:10.250: W/dalvikvm(698): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
11-12 19:09:10.260: E/AndroidRuntime(698): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 19:09:10.260: E/AndroidRuntime(698): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
11-12 19:09:10.260: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:229)
11-12 19:09:10.260: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3620)
11-12 19:09:10.260: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at com.example.pokethedot.PokeTheDot$1.onClick(PokeTheDot.java:29)
11-12 19:09:10.260: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
11-12 19:09:10.260: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
11-12 19:09:10.260: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-12 19:09:10.260: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-12 19:09:10.260: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-12 19:09:10.260: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-12 19:09:10.260: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 19:09:10.260: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-12 19:09:10.260: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-12 19:09:10.260: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-12 19:09:10.260: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 19:09:23.040: E/Trace(723): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-12 19:09:23.560: D/dalvikvm(723): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 102K, 3% free 8153K/8327K, paused 30ms, total 31ms
11-12 19:09:23.560: I/dalvikvm-heap(723): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.800MB for 829456-byte allocation
11-12 19:09:23.610: D/dalvikvm(723): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 3% free 8962K/9159K, paused 21ms+3ms, total 50ms
11-12 19:09:23.790: D/gralloc_goldfish(723): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-12 19:09:24.860: W/ResourceType(723): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000001
11-12 19:09:24.860: D/AndroidRuntime(723): Shutting down VM
11-12 19:09:24.860: W/dalvikvm(723): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
11-12 19:09:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(723): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 19:09:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(723): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
11-12 19:09:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:229)
11-12 19:09:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3620)
11-12 19:09:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at com.example.pokethedot.PokeTheDot$1.onClick(PokeTheDot.java:29)
11-12 19:09:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
11-12 19:09:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
11-12 19:09:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-12 19:09:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-12 19:09:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-12 19:09:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-12 19:09:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 19:09:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-12 19:09:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-12 19:09:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-12 19:09:24.870: E/AndroidRuntime(723):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1  and  PokeTheDot$1.onClick(PokeTheDot.java:29) is important. Look at your file `PokeTheDot` at line `29`, there you are accessing something that isn't there – maybe not initialized or you don't have access. apparently it has something to do with a String resource from your strings.xml

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
display.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
```

Using an int as parameter for `setText` means you want to use a string resource, in this case, the resource with the id `#0x1` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

make

```
int couter;
Button add;
```

as final,

```
final int counter;
final Button add;
```

and change

```
display.setText(counter);
```

as

```
display.setText(new String(counter));
```

This might solve your problem. You must use final variables inside the anonymous classes.